# Publish to Shinyapps.io, ERROR cannot change working directory

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

My code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(xlsx)
library(rsconnect)

setwd("C:/Users/John/Documents/golfersTools/golferAPP")
golfstats <- read.csv("golfers_app.csv", header = TRUE)


ui <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Golfers and their tools"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(


      selectInput("golfstatInput", " Golf Stat Choice",
                              choices = c("drivers", "irons", "putter", "balls"), 
                             selected = "irons" )),
    mainPanel( plotOutput("plotOutput"),
               br(), br(),
               tableOutput("results")
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  golfstats <- read.csv("golfers_app.csv", header = TRUE)
  .e <- environment()
  environment = environment()

    output$plotOutput <- renderPlot({


      if (input$golfstatInput == "irons"){

        i <- ggplot(golfstats, aes(x= reorder(golfstats$PLAYER.NAME, -golfstats$X.GIR),
                               y= golfstats$X.GIR, fill=golfstats$Irons), envrionment = .e ) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
          xlab("Player") + ylab("GIR %") + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(50,75)) +
          ggtitle("Brand of Irons for highest GIR %") + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Iron Brand") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
    print(i) 

      }


      if (input$golfstatInput == "drivers"){


        d <- ggplot(golfstats, aes(x= reorder(golfstats$PLAYER.NAME, -golfstats$AVG.),
                                 y= golfstats$AVG., fill=golfstats$Type.of.Driver), environment = .e ) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
          xlab("Player") + ylab("Average Drive distance") + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(250,320)) +
          ggtitle("Brand of Driver for PGA golfers with longest Avg Drive") + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Driver Brand") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
        print(d)

      }

      if (input$golfstatInput == "putter"){


        d <- ggplot(golfstats, aes(x= reorder(golfstats$PLAYER.NAME, golfstats$Avg.Putts),
                                 y= golfstats$Avg.Putts, fill=golfstats$PutterUsed), environment = .e ) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
          xlab("Player") + ylab("Average Number of Putts") + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1,2)) +
          ggtitle("Brand of Putter for PGA golfers with lowest Avg Putts") + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Putter Brand") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
        print(d)

      }


      if (input$golfstatInput == "balls"){


        d <- ggplot(golfstats, aes(x= reorder(golfstats$PLAYER.NAME, golfstats$ave.score),
                                   y= golfstats$ave.score, fill=golfstats$ball.used), environment = .e ) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
          xlab("Player") + ylab("Average Score") + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(50,80)) +
          ggtitle("Brand of Ball for PGA golfers with lowest Avg Score") + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Ball Brand") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
        print(d)

      }

    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I keep getting the error, cannot change the working directory from shinyapps.io. I have a feeling my issue has to do with my local data being published to the server. I tried publishing by running RStudio as an administrator. I've looked all over google and have yet to find a similar problem (with solution attached) does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: C:/Users/John/Documents/golfersTools/golferAPP does not exists on shinyapps.io domain and you dont need to set the working directory there (production), since it is the directory of the app itself. The convention says you should have an /data/ folder and put all your data there... then you use read.csv("./data/your_file.csv"). Take a look at: http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/